# Unable to upload a media file on S3 servers from Android using Retrofit

Tags: android, file-upload, amazon-s3, retrofit, multipart

I am using Retrofit library to upload media files (multipart) from my Android application. The servers are on Amazon using S3.
I am getting this following error :

```
05-15 20:17:38.515: W/System.err(649): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0x5eed7ca0: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
```

Few points :
1. I have tested the API using POSTMAN and it is working perfectly. (no issues with max upload size as well.)

2. Weirdly this is running(uploading) successfully in one of my phones ie Moto E. The phone it is not working includes Moto G2 and Xperia SP as of now.

3. I am able to make normal requests through Retrofit successfully. Its uploading media files that is an issue.

Here is the code to upload :

```
@Multipart
@POST("/journeys/{journey_id}/videos")
public void uploadVideo(
        @Path("journey_id") String journeyId,
        @Part("api_key") TypedString apiKey, 
        @Part("video[user_id]") TypedString userId,
        @Part("video[video_file]") TypedFile video, 
        Callback<String> callback);

public static void uploadVideo(final Context context, final Video video) {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setConverter(new StringConverter())
            .setEndpoint(Constants.TRAVELJAR_API_BASE_URL).build();
    TravelJarServices myService = restAdapter.create(TravelJarServices.class);

    myService.uploadVideo(TJPreferences.getActiveJourneyId(context), new TypedString(
            TJPreferences.getApiKey(context)),
            new TypedString(TJPreferences.getUserId(context)), new TypedFile("video/*",
                    new File(video.getDataLocalURL())), new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void success(String str, retrofit.client.Response response) {
                    try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "video uploaded successfully " + str);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "error in uploading video" + retrofitError);
                    retrofitError.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
}
```

I have been researching on this issue for a while now and cannot come to a solution. I don't want to switch to another library as this should work for me as well. Any help will be highly appreciated. TIA

Comment: What is the endpoint ? Your S3 bucket ? If so this means you allow anyone to upload file. You would need AWS client to do it or use an intermediary server.

Comment: @inmyth I am uploading through a rails server. Plus I am able to upload files using POSTMAN perfectly. So I am guessing there shouldn't be an issue with the server.